# Alamofire : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." on trying to shift from https to http on same app session

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurl, urlsession, nsurlerrordomain

We have similar servers on two types of hardware devices, which we need to connect to using iOS application. Currently we are using Alamofire 4.9.1 for all the API requests.

**Previously we supported only http endpoints on our servers, but recently we have moved to https on latest version of the devices.The app needs to support both.**

The issue that we are facing is, when we connect to a **Device X(which supports https)**, and then try to connect to **Device Y(which only support http)**, we are getting this error

```
[Error] GET 'http://172.30.1.1/file.xml' [27.7252 s]:

Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={​​​​​​​NSUnderlyingError=0x281f2fde0 {​​​​​​​Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={​​​​​​​_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}​​​​​​​}​​​​​​​, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://172.30.1.1/file.xml, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://172.30.1.1/file.xml, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}​​​​​​​
```

Connecting to device Y(http) directly without first connecting to Device X(https) works fine, and after the error if we kill the app we are able to connect to Device Y(http). This happens even though we are using different SessionManagers in Alamofire.

Is this because we are using the same ip address? If we check the error **NSErrorFailingURLStringKey**, it is still https although the url we are calling is http.

I am pasting the relevant code here

```
    private var manager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        manager.retrier = RetryHandler()
        return manager
    }()

    private var manager2: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        var serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "172.30.1.1": .disableEvaluation
        ]
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
       
        //Adding TrustManager to Allow All Certificates
        let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: config, serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies))
        manager.adapter = RequestInterceptor()
        manager.retrier = RequestInterceptor()
        
        return manager
    }()
```

Things we have already tried :

- Use different UrlSessionConfiguration
- Set config.urlCache = nil

Comment: Is it possible you work with App Transport Security Settings wrong?

Comment: We haven't changed anything in ATS from our previous versions. As I said http requests work fine, if they are used first. I suspect some caching is happening somewhere.